# Click highlight no longer overlaps html element in phonegap html5 app

Tags: html, cordova, outline

I have a phonegap html5 application running on andriod.
Following some changes I did the "highlight" that marks clicked elements now does not show up when it should. (I am referring to the highlight controlled by `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`).

I am looking to understand if this could be some wrong doing of mine or did I hit some webkit bug.
What can cause something like this?

I apologize for not providing code as the actual code is very complicated script generated HTML and css. If I could recreate it using simple code I would have been halfway to the solution.

Thanks